# Parsing flags from bytes in Elixir

Tags: elixir, mask, flags

I have two bytes in hex format, like "0c" or "31".
How do I map that to some flag values? I want a list of all flags that are set.

Example:

```
"0c" -> 0000 1100 -> [:flag3, :flag2]
"31" -> 0011 0001 -> [:flag5, :flag4, :flag0]
```

Here each flag is named by its position but later I want to have flags with more descriptive names.

Getting from hex is easy, just `String.to_integer("0c", 16)`, but after that I get lost in the world of `Bitwise`.

Comment: Wow--three strong answers to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with binary pattern matching:

*Level “easy”*. Just pattern match.

```rb
<<i1::1,i2::1,i3::1,i4::1,i5::1,i6::1,i7::1,i8::1>> =
  <<String.to_integer("0c", 16)>>
#⇒ "\f"
{i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6,i7,i8}
#⇒ {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}
```

Yes, we have all the flags (named `i` above for the sake of shortness) mapped out of the box.

To convert them to list of `:flagN` atoms:

```rb
[i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6,i7,i8]
|> Enum.reverse()
|> Enum.with_index()
|> Enum.reduce([], fn
     {0, _}, acc -> acc
     {_, idx}, acc -> [:"flag#{idx}" | acc]
   end)
[:flag3, :flag2]
```

---

*Level “intermediate”*. Create a function that takes a `String` and produces the tuple.

```rb
def flags(input) do
  # possibly some checks of input to fail fast
  <<i1::1,i2::1,i3::1,i4::1,i5::1,i6::1,i7::1,i8::1>> =
    <<String.to_integer(input, 16)>>
  {i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6,i7,i8}
end
```

---

*Level “advanced”*. Produce a macro that will produce functions for the input of any length (or just produce functions directly in the body of the module.)

```rb
defmodule Flags do
  Enum.each(1..10, fn i ->
    # generate a function for `String`s of length 1–10 here
  end)
end
```

---

*Bonus track.* Exporting `flag0` .. `flag7` variables to the current context bypassing [macros hygiene](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/macros.html#macros-hygiene):

```rb
defmodule Flags do
  defmacro flags(input) do
    mapper =
      {:<<>>, [],
       0..7
       |> Enum.map(& {:::, [], [{:var!, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel],
                                        [{:"flag#{&1}", [], Elixir}]}, 1]})
       |> Enum.reverse()
      }
    quote do
      unquote(mapper) = <<String.to_integer(unquote(input), 16)>>
    end
  end
end

defmodule Flags.Test do
  import Flags

  def test do
    flags("0c")

    [flag0,flag1,flag2,flag3,flag4,flag5,flag6,flag7]
    |> Enum.with_index()
    |> Enum.reduce([], fn
          {0, _}, acc -> acc
         {_, idx}, acc -> [:"flag#{idx}" | acc]
       end)
    |> IO.inspect(label: "Result")
    IO.inspect(flag2, label: "Flag2")
  end
end

Flags.Test.test
#⇒ Result: [:flag3, :flag2]
#  Flag2: 1
```

In the latter example, there are *local variables* `flagN` becomes defined (to either zero or one) after the call to `flags("0c")`.

Comment: Converting these tuples to the list of atoms OP wants would require a lot more code though.

Comment: @Dogbert I have updated an answer with a conversion to the list of atoms, it’s not “a lot more code” btw. And it’s still clearer than bitwise IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

@Igor has posted two good solutions for arbitrary sized inputs but if you only have 1 or a fixed number of bytes, you can do it in a one liner (here I'm assuming 1 byte / 8 bits of input; just change `n` to the number of bits you want to check if you have more):

```
for i <- 0..7, (n >>> i &&& 1) == 1, do: :"flag#{i}"
```

```
iex(1)> use Bitwise
Bitwise
iex(2)> n = "31" |> String.to_integer(16)
49
iex(3)> for i <- 0..7, (n >>> i &&& 1) == 1, do: :"flag#{i}"
[:flag0, :flag4, :flag5]
iex(4)> n = "0c" |> String.to_integer(16)
12
iex(5)> for i <- 0..7, (n >>> i &&& 1) == 1, do: :"flag#{i}"
[:flag2, :flag3]
```

For each number from 0 to 7, we check if that bit is set in the integer, and if so, convert it to an atom and collect it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually "the world of `Bitwise`" can be avoided by string manipulations:

```
"0c"
|> String.to_integer(16) # 12
|> Integer.to_string(2) # "1100"
|> String.codepoints # ["1", "1", "0", "0"]
|> Enum.reverse # ["0", "0", "1", "1"]
|> Enum.with_index # [{"0", 0}, {"0", 1}, {"1", 2}, {"1", 3}]
|> Enum.reduce([], fn
    {"1", index}, acc -> [:"flag#{index}" | acc]
    _, acc -> acc
  end) # [:flag3, :flag2]
```

Otherwise, it can be calculated something like the following:

```
defmodule FlagBuilder do
  use Bitwise

  def build_flags(number, index \\ 0)
  def build_flags(0, _) do
    []
  end
  def build_flags(number, index) do
    next = fn -> build_flags(number >>> 1, index + 1) end

    case number &&& 1 do
      0 -> next.()
      1 -> [:"flag#{index}" | next.()]
    end
  end
end

a = "31"
|> String.to_integer(16) # 12
|> FlagBuilder.build_flags
```

The idea is to find out the last bit (by using `&&& 1`) and build a flag, if the last bit is `1`. The number given into the next iteration is the input number shifted to the right on that one bit (by using `>>> 1`)